# Problem with SSH when trying to connect to my Ubuntu server with my phone

Tags: networking, server, ssh, android

I don't know why but whenever I try to connect to my Ubuntu server with my phone it doesn't work but if I do it from my Windows PC, whether using the CMD or PuTTy, it does work.
When using the command `service ssh status` I get this message:

```
sep 13 13:05:52 serverPC sshd[9492]: Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.17 port 59365: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

I also do not understand why always the port is anything but 22.

I really need to be able to SSH to my server with my phone.

*Phone: Samsung Galaxy S21 FE*

*Used app: Mobile SSH*

Comment: How are you trying to log in? keys, password, etc? This really sounds like it's a problem with the settings in your phone app.

Comment: The port 59365 is the port the client (your phone tried to connect from). Id use juicessh from google play store. It always works for me. I have a s20 fe.

Comment: that app seems really bad, just try another ssh client. that error means the client app doesn't support any authentication method provided by your ssh server